# URL issues with Django 4

Tags: python, django, django-4.0

I've been using Django since Django 1, and I've always used the same URL patterns (except when we switched from url to path).

Now I'm having an issue with 404 errors. I'll give you my Project URLS, and App URLS, and you tell me what am I doing wrong:

Project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('b/', include('booking.urls')),
]
```

Booking App:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('book/<int:s>/<str:d>/', views.book, name="book"),
    path('fb/', views.finalize_booking, name="finalize_booking"),
]
```

When I try to call `{% url "finalize_booking" %}`, it gives me a 404 error.

Comment: when I add a slash at the end of the url, it works, but I don't know how to do that in {% url.....%}. Also, I do not want to add the trailing slash, I want things to be the way they were before.

Comment: path('fb', ....) should do it

Comment: {% url "finalize_booking" %} is ok in the template.  What is the complete error message?

Comment: @Razenstein when I do that, and I visit .../fb it gives me 404

Comment: according to your urls.py files it should now be server/b/fb/   .... can you please post the complete error message

Comment: The error message is a 404 page not found, there is no trace for that.

Comment: Is debug=True in settings.py?

Comment: Yes! I have Debug On that is why it gives me the 404 error in the yellow page.

Comment: Please post that "yellow" error trace

Answer (score 0):

You should add forward slash at the start of of your string.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('/book/<int:s>/<str:d>/', views.book, name="book"),
path('/fb/', views.finalize_booking, name="finalize_booking"),]
```

Comment: No, actually it is not the solution. The beginning of the slash should actually be the trailing slash in the previous root. But thank you for answering.